# Where to place insert to write to MongoDB in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, scope, closures

I am trying to build a very simple script to insert content into mongo using node.  Here is what I have so far.  I took out all error catching/logging in order to show simple code

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName'; 
var db;
var collection;

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    collection = db.collection('myCollection');
    insertFunction();
});

function insertFunction(){
    var entry = {name: 'testUser1'};  // in final be function returning entry
    collection.insertOne(entry);
}
```

This code throws the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null

Which has me very confused.  The normal rule is that if you define a variable (db) inside a closure without proceeding it with `var` it is given a global scope.  Why then has collection become `null` by the time it is used in the handler function?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code to my system and ran `node script.js` and it did not provide an error.  The script hung because you did not close the db connection, but there was no error.  I checked and dbName was created as well as a collection called myCollection containing one document.  I added `db.close()` at line 10 and it no longer hangs.  How are you running this script?

Comment: I'm using Node v6.9.1 and Mongo v3.4.0-rc2 on Centos 7.1.